# Is this way of iterating pythonic?

Tags: arrays, iteration, python-3.7

I am trying to iterate through a list, and my code is ugly.

```
        elements=[]
    value_and_position=[]
    for element in tiles:
        elements.append(element.get_attribute('class'))
```

I feel like I've seen a more pythonic way of writing a for loop like that. Anyone have it?

Comment: what is `get_attribute('class')` list element dosent have any such attribute

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
value_and_position=[]
elements = [element.get_attribute('class') for element in tiles]
```